# c# - validating signed XML

Tags: c#, xml, asp.net-mvc, signedxml

I have a problem with validating signed XML.
Maybe you can help me :)

I have an ASP.NET MVC service, which receives an XML and I need to validate if signature in this XML is valid.

Certificate I'm using for validation looks like this:

cert.crt file:

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIDcjCCAlqgAwIBAgIFALVBJRQwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEFBQAwaTELMAkGA1UEBhMCREUxDz ............
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

My code for signature validation:

```
var xmlDoc = new XmlDocument { PreserveWhitespace = true };
xmlDoc.LoadXml(samlXML);

var signedXml = new SignedXml(xmlDoc);

var certPath = HostingEnvironment.MapPath(@"~/App_Data/cert.crt");
var readAllBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(certPath);

X509Certificate2 certificate = new X509Certificate2(readAllBytes);

XmlNodeList signatureElement = xmlDoc.GetElementsByTagName("ds:Signature");
signedXml.LoadXml((XmlElement)signatureElement[0]);

var isValid = signedXml.CheckSignature(certificate, true);
```

XML is signed by :

```
<ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1"/>
```

This line

```
X509Certificate2 certificate = new X509Certificate2(readAllBytes);
```

Throws an error

```
Object was not found.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you check certPath, is it correct and is the file there?

Comment: @ShinoLex yes
line `var readAllBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(certPath);` works fine

Answer (score 0):

According to the docs the byte array must be either binary encoded (DER format) or Base64-encoded X.509 data. You have something else on your hands, which is why the constructor can't handle your data.

Check the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509certificate2.-ctor?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Security_Cryptography_X509Certificates_X509Certificate2__ctor_System_Byte___) for more information.